# How to get IP Address in a PageMethod?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, pagemethods

Using jQuery, my client side is calling Vote from a page method. The signature of the webmethod is below.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Vote(int selectedAnswer, int pollID, string userToken) {
    ... }
```

My question is in Vote(),  how do I reference Page.Request so I can get the user's IP Address? In a normal page load method, I'm able to reference Page.Request because the page load method is NOT static, where Vote is.

Comment: Since this question is completely answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964659/get-ip-address-of-the-requested-client-soap-message, I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get it using: System.Web.HttpContext.Current

As the name implies HttpContext.Current gets the current HTTP context.  You can get the Request object from the current context and go from there.